# Multiple instances of Windows Powershell in one window

Tags: windows, powershell

I tried to open multiple instances of Powershell in one window only by searching online but there was no satisfactory solution.
Can anybody tell the command to open more than 1instances in only one window?

Comment: It's not clear why you want to do this. As a wild guess: have you tried sessions (`get-help about_PSSessions`)?

Comment: If you're ok with using Powsershell ISE it lets you use tabs like in a browser. File > New PowerShellTab

Comment: Do you mean a tabbed interface? Have you web searched for "powershell tabbed interface"?

Comment: @montonero I want to open nodejs lite server and simultaneously update my changes on github and that's why I want to have 2 instances of powershell running simultaneously in 1 window. I tried `get-help` command but as I am a new user of Powershell so didn't understood anything that appeared after that.

Comment: @BrainRenticus Thanks it worked for me. Just the interface is a little bit new so I am guessing is there anyway to do the same thing in Powershell?

Comment: @music2myear Yes I meant that and now I searched it too. And it is showing to use Powershell ISE. Thanks for giving me correct words that I should have used in my query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerShell on Windows comes with two primary UIs: The *normal* PowerShell CLI interface, and the PowerShell ISE (Integrated Scripting Environment).

Like most normal cli interfaces, the regular PS window is a simple, single-window UI that allows for full but unfeatured use of PowerShell.

The ISE adds several features including a command reference view, a script pane separate from the CLI pane, and a two-level tabbed interface.

The **basic tabs** are only for the script panes, allowing you to work in multiple scripts and a single PS instance. You open these by clicking File > New <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> (or Open <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) to create a blank new script or an existing script in a new script pane.

The **secondary tabs** open new PS instances. You open these by clicking File > New PowerShell Tab <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (or Remote PowerShell Tab <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).

Each PowerShell Tab can have multiple script tabs open with it. The script tabs are not shared between the PowerShell tabs.

**However**, there is some evidence that Microsoft has stopped actively developing the ISE. They still issue bug fixes, and most of the core function is pretty simple and relies on features already baked in to PowerShell, but you're unlikely to see new abilities or features added to the ISE. Instead, most ISE/IDE development effort is being routed to the open-source and very capable Visual Studio Code application, which is free, frequently updated, and, like I mentioned earlier, very capable. With the official PowerShell plugin VS Code becomes an excellent replacement for PowerShell ISE and is what I use myself. Some of the new-user features of ISE, such as the Command pane, are more visible front-and-center, but if you use Atom or are already familiar with other IDEs and want some of that more full-featured function in your PS environment, the VS Code application is well worth looking at.

Answer (score 3):

An improved answer would be the *Windows Terminal* application that you can get via the Microsoft store and is created by MS

Here is the product definition:

```
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/
```

Here is the link to where you can get it:

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab
```

It also works for other terminals such as your WSL or CMD

Enjoy!